# How to resolve Laravel version conflicts between 4.1 installation and 4.0 dependant packages required in composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install the laravelodbc package to use with the laravel framework. I initially installed laravel using `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`. I then added `"jtgrimes/laravelodbc": "0.2.*"` to my composer.json file and added `'jtgrimes\Laravelodbc\ODBCServiceProvider'` to my list of providers in app.php.

The `require` key in my `composer.json` file looks like:

```
"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
  "yajra/laravel-oci8": "*",
  "jtgrimes/laravelodbc": "*"
},
```

When I try to run `composer update` as is suggested in the [laravelodbc readme](https://github.com/jtgrimes/laravelodbc).

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages, the following message is given:

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.1
    - jtgrimes/laravelodbc 0.1.1 requires illuminate/database 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9], illuminate/database[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - jtgrimes/laravelodbc 0.1.2 requires illuminate/database 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9], illuminate/database[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - jtgrimes/laravelodbc 0.1.3 requires illuminate/database 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9], illuminate/database[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - jtgrimes/laravelodbc 0.1.4 requires illuminate/database 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9], illuminate/database[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - jtgrimes/laravelodbc 0.2.0 requires illuminate/database 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9], illuminate/database[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - jtgrimes/laravelodbc dev-master requires illuminate/database 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9], illuminate/database[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA3].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA4].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.10].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.6].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.9].
    - don't install illuminate/database 4.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.0-BETA2|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.0-BETA3|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.0-BETA4|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Installation request for jtgrimes/laravelodbc * -> satisfiable by jtgrimes/laravelodbc[0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.2.0, dev-master].
```

**Edit** 
I was experimenting with different versions of laravel to see if that fixed my problem and forgot to change it back when I posted the question. The correct version of laravel is now displayed above, and with the same resulting message as shown above.

**Edit 2**
I tried your suggestion, my fork is [here](https://github.com/Purkinje/laravelodbc) (notice the change to the composer.json file there). I also changed the `composer.json` file in my laravel project:

```
"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
  "yajra/laravel-oci8": "*",
  "Purkinje/laravelodbc": "*"
},
```

...

```
"repositories": [
        {
                "type": "vcs",
                "url": "https://github.com/Purkinje/laravelodbc"
        }
],
```

When I run `composer update`, I get the error:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package purkinje/laravelodbc could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Comment: try "type" : "git", as suggested. I didnt test that code, but it should work.

Comment: I got the "type": "vcs" syntax from [here](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs).

Comment: did you try with "git" syntax ?

Comment: Yes, but using the `https://` protocol instead of `git://`. My main problem was that there were still a few mentions of the old package author in the `composer.json` file of my forked `laravelodbc` repo. Once those were changed over to `Purkinje`, that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Laravel 4.1 (as a result of the installation command you instantiated a project based on the actual 4.1 release) you might run into some version conflicts - as 4.1 is around just for a month or so.

Notice that in you "jtgrimes/laravelodbc" package composer.json file you have

```
 "illuminate/support": "4.0.x",
                "illuminate/database": "4.0.x"
    },
```

so it's an obvoius version conflict, as you have 4.1 installed.

A quick fix is to just create a new project based on Laravel 4.0, so you can easily install all the packages without the need to fork them on Github

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist your_project_name 4.0`

Another fix is to fork the project on github, change the composer.json file to include 4.1 versioning and than point your composer to install from your forked version, by adding a reference to a git repo:

```
repositories": [
   {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "git://github.com/your-github-username/yourfork.git"
   }
]
```

Bear in mind that the 4.0->4.1 change does imply some changes in use of certain Laravel features , so in some cases the package might not work as expected (or at all) when boosted to 4.1 usage. See laravel.com/docs/upgrade for details.

Comment: where does the `repositories` bit of code go? In the laravel project's composer.json file?

Comment: I think I found that the answer is yes, see [here](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository).

Comment: I'm trying your first suggestions because I'd rather stay on a current version of Laravel, if possible.

Comment: good choice but bear in mind that the 4.0->4.1 change does imply some changes in use of certain Laravel features , so in some cases the package might not work as expected (or at all) when boosted to 4.1 usage. See http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade for details.